# What is causing my wireless router to stop routing HTTP (port 80) connections?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, router, http

My 802.11g router (Belkin F5D7230-4 v2000) periodically stops transmitting HTTP data on port 80. My laptop is the sole client connected to it (on channel 9 with WPA-AES encryption), and there are about 10 to 15 other wireless networks in the vicinity. I've noticed that:

- The problem usually occurs after opening many concurrent HTTP connections (however, browsing Gmail or Facebook alone works fine). Also, exercising my bandwidth by downloading a file at 1.5MB/s appears to increase the likelihood of the problem.
- The problem doesn't fix itself. Turning my laptop's wireless switch on then off doesn't help. I need to restart the router or reset its LAN settings (e.g., router IP address, subnet mask, and DHCP lease time).
- I can access the router's admin interface over HTTP. However, I can't reach any external sites like http://google.com.
- Connections on ports other than 80 still work. Specifically, I can establish new ping, AIM, Skype, and HTTPS connections. In addition, HTTP connections on port 8080 do work.
- From looking at Apache logs, web servers listening on port 80 do not receive requests from my computer; therefore, the router seems to be failing to send outgoing HTTP requests.
- I don't have the equipment to verify this, but I seem to remember that even wired clients failed to establish HTTP connections once the router entered this state.

Unfortunately my lack of networking expertise and the strange symptoms are leaving me rather confused.

EDIT: It seems to be an inherent flaw with this model of router. It might be time to start looking into custom firmware...

- [Belkin Wireless Router Dropping Port 80](http://www.techsupportforum.com/networking-forum/networking-support/351841-belkin-wireless-router-dropping-port-80-a.html)
- [7230-4 v2000 strange connectivity issue](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/remark,13182931)
- [F5D7230-4 v2000 Drops HTTP (Port 80) Connectivity](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/remark,13397929)

Comment: DD-WRT has firmware for that particular model...http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database

Answer (score 0):

As you mention custom firmware but not updates to the devices firmware, it is worth looking at the manufacturer's site for updates. Even if you bought the device yesterday it could still have firmware a year or more out of date as and it will have sat on shelves in the store and warehouses for a while (and manufacturers don't always immediately change the outgoing kit on new firmware releases).

Comment: I have the latest firmware (4.05.03) that is available for the v2000 series. The router is from 2005 or 2006 and there haven't been any firmware updates since, so I was considering DD-WRT micro-plus but it apparently disables the wired LAN ports.